# How does this C++ template class code work?

Tags: c++, templates, googletest

I am trying to port Google Test ([gtest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/)) code to VxWorks 5.5. The serious drawback is that development environment Tornado 2.2 uses ancient GCC compiler version 2.96.

While analyzing the code I've located part of the code in `gtest.h` I do not understand! How this C++ template class is functioning?

```
// ImplicitlyConvertible<From, To>::value is a compile-time bool
// constant that's true iff type From can be implicitly converted to
// type To.
template <typename From, typename To>
class ImplicitlyConvertible {
 private:
  // We need the following helper functions only for their types.
  // They have no implementations.

  // MakeFrom() is an expression whose type is From.  We cannot simply
  // use From(), as the type From may not have a public default
  // constructor.
  static From MakeFrom();

  // These two functions are overloaded.  Given an expression
  // Helper(x), the compiler will pick the first version if x can be
  // implicitly converted to type To; otherwise it will pick the
  // second version.
  //
  // The first version returns a value of size 1, and the second
  // version returns a value of size 2.  Therefore, by checking the
  // size of Helper(x), which can be done at compile time, we can tell
  // which version of Helper() is used, and hence whether x can be
  // implicitly converted to type To.
  static char Helper(To);
  static char (&Helper(...))[2];  // NOLINT

  // We have to put the 'public' section after the 'private' section,
  // or MSVC refuses to compile the code.
 public:
  // MSVC warns about implicitly converting from double to int for
  // possible loss of data, so we need to temporarily disable the
  // warning.
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# pragma warning(push)          // Saves the current warning state.
# pragma warning(disable:4244)  // Temporarily disables warning 4244.

  static const bool value =
      sizeof(Helper(ImplicitlyConvertible::MakeFrom())) == 1;
# pragma warning(pop)           // Restores the warning state.
#elif defined(__BORLANDC__)
  // C++Builder cannot use member overload resolution during template
  // instantiation.  The simplest workaround is to use its C++0x type traits
  // functions (C++Builder 2009 and above only).
  static const bool value = __is_convertible(From, To);
#else
  static const bool value =
      sizeof(Helper(ImplicitlyConvertible::MakeFrom())) == 1;
#endif  // _MSV_VER
};
```

When object of this class is created, boolean variable with the name `value` should contain the answer if template type `From` is implicitly convertible to template type `To`. To get the answer, two private functions are used, `MakeFrom()` and `Helper()`. But these  two functions are only declared here, and I cannot find definition for neither of them. If nothing else, this implementation should not link.

Neither do I understand the syntax of the following

```
static char (&Helper(...))[2];
```

Of course, this code compiles just fine (under Microsoft Visual C++ 7.1 or newer  or GCC 3.4 or newer) and guys at Google know exactly what they are doing.

Please enlighten me! Not understanding this code will make me go crazy!  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a standard trick with template programming.

Note that the comments say *"by checking the size of Helper(x)"*: this underscores that the *only* thing the code does with `Helper` is evaluate `sizeof(Helper(x))` for some `x`. The [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator *does not actually evaluate its argument* (it doesn't need to; it only needs to find out how large it is, which is possible using only information available at compile time) and this is why there is no linker error (`Helper` is never really called).

The syntax that gives you trouble means that `Helper` is a function that accepts any number and type of parameters and returns a reference to a `char[2]`. To write a signature for this type of function (a [*variadic function*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic)) one needs to use ellipsis (`...`) as the specification for the last argument.

Variadic functions are a feature inherited from C that should generally be avoided and that wreaks havoc when used with class types, but in this case it does not matter because -- as mentioned earlier -- `Helper` will not be actually called.

The class ties this all together by allowing you to use the syntax

```
ImplicitlyConvertible<From, To>::value
```

To produce `value`, the code "fakes" calling `Helper` and passing it an instance of `From` as an argument¹. It relies on the compiler's overload resolution to determine if the overload that takes a `To` would be called in this scenario; if so, the return value of that overload is `char` which has a guaranteed size of `1` and `value` ends up being `true`. Otherwise the variadic overload (which can take any type of argument) is selected, which returns a `char[2]`. This has a size greater than `1`, so `value` ends up `false`.

---

¹ Note that here the "`sizeof` does not actually evaluate the expression" trick is used again: how do you tell the compiler that the argument to `Helper` is an instance of `From`? You could use `From()`, but then `From` would need to have a default public constructor for the code to compile. So you just tell the compiler "I have a function `MakeFrom` that returns a `From`" -- the function will not be actually called.